# How to disable rounding of values in JSpinner

Tags: java, swing, numbers, rounding, jspinner

I have a `JSpinner` with maximum number of fraction digits as 6. So when I enter `1.1234567` it is getting rounded off to `1.123457`.

But my requirement is when the user enters the value as a free text I want to disable the rounding and set the value to spinner as such (`1.1234567`). However if the user clicks on the spinner arrow button, it can be rounded.

Answer (score 4):

The value is typically formatted by the `JSpinner`'s editor.  You change how the editor formats the display value, which will leave the actual model value unchanged

The editor is usually backed by a `JFormattedTextField`, it'd be nice just to be able to grab it a configure it...

There's probably a few ways to do this, but I choose to use a `NumberFormat` as I know how to control the number of fraction digits and the rounding mode

First, we need a implementation of a `JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter`

```
public class NumberFormatFormatter extends DefaultFormatter {

    private NumberFormat format;

    public NumberFormatFormatter(NumberFormat format) {
        this.format = format;
    }

    @Override
    public Object stringToValue(String string) throws ParseException {
        System.out.println("stringToValue: " + string);
        return format.parse(string);
    }

    @Override
    public String valueToString(Object value) throws ParseException {           
        String text = format.format(value);
        System.out.println("valueToString: " + value + "; " + text);
        return text;
    }

}
```

This is then wrapped in a `AbstractFormatterFactory`

```
NumberFormat numberInstance = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
numberInstance.setMaximumFractionDigits(6);
numberInstance.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
numberInstance.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);

JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter format = new NumberFormatFormatter(numberInstance);
DefaultFormatterFactory dff = new DefaultFormatterFactory(format);
```

We then configure the `JSpinner` and it's create a new `NumberEditor` to suit our needs

```
JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel());
JSpinner.NumberEditor editor = new JSpinner.NumberEditor(spinner, "0.0#####");
JFormattedTextField textField = editor.getTextField();
textField.setFormatterFactory(dff);
textField.setColumns(10);
spinner.setEditor(editor);
```

Don't forget to apply the editor to the `JSpinner` ;).

This might seem like a lot (I certainly think so), but it wouldn't take much to wrap it into your own implementation of a editor class which simply took a `NumberFormat` as parameter, as an idea.

This approach leaves the "display" to the editor, but won't affect the underlying value in the model, so, if you enter `1.123456789`, the model will still return `1.123456789`, but it will display `1.123456`

Take a look at [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) and [How to Use Spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) for more details

[image: Spinner]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatter;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatterFactory;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {

            NumberFormat numberInstance = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
            numberInstance.setMaximumFractionDigits(6);
            numberInstance.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
            numberInstance.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);

            JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter format = new NumberFormatFormatter(numberInstance);
            DefaultFormatterFactory dff = new DefaultFormatterFactory(format);

            JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel());
            JSpinner.NumberEditor editor = new JSpinner.NumberEditor(spinner, "#0.######");
            JFormattedTextField textField = editor.getTextField();
            textField.setFormatterFactory(dff);
            textField.setColumns(10);
            spinner.setEditor(editor);

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            spinner.setValue(1.1234567d);

            add(spinner);
        }

        public class NumberFormatFormatter extends DefaultFormatter {

            private NumberFormat format;

            public NumberFormatFormatter(NumberFormat format) {
                this.format = format;
            }

            @Override
            public Object stringToValue(String string) throws ParseException {
                System.out.println("stringToValue: " + string);
                return format.parse(string);
            }

            @Override
            public String valueToString(Object value) throws ParseException {
                String text = format.format(value);
                System.out.println("valueToString: " + value + "; " + text);
                return text;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: RoundingMode.DOWN is shot inside stars, HALF_UP is close to MsExcel

Comment: @mKorbel In that case, you can use what ever meets the requirements...I don't `JFormattedText`, takes to much effort to configure :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks for your answer. Is there any way to control the display of the editor? I need to display the exact value when the user inputs as a free text.

Comment: The question there is, how would you know?  Basically how it works is the underlying `Document` of the text field is updated, this triggers a series of events which allow the value to be (eventually) formatted, when the user leaves the field or press [Enter], the field is validated and the final value is formatted.  The problem is, if you use `setValue`, you get the same result

Comment: Is there any way to stop formatting when the user manually enters the value and press enter.

Comment: @Madhumitharavindran The question still is, how would you know?  The parts of the API making the decision simply don't know how the change occurs, only that the change has occured

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you can do is to create your own JSpinner Model, something similar to:

```
public class CustomSpinnerModel extends AbstractSpinnerModel {

    private Double value;

    public CustomSpinnerModel(Double value){
         this.value=value;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getNextValue() {
        value+=0.0000001;
        return value+"";//return as string to avoid round
    }

    @Override
    public Object getPreviousValue() {
        value-=0.0000001;
        return value+"";//return as string to avoid round
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValue() {
        return value+"";//return as string to avoid round
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(Object object) {
        try{
           value=Double.parseDouble(object);
        } catch(Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But a small question. if I apply this model to my spinner, even if I click on spinner arrow button, it will not be rounded rite?

Comment: I didn't try it, but it should not, if it is considered the values as Text class. If it did not work maybe you have to create it from 0. 
Creating a JtextFields on a JPanel with 2 JButtons, and with this you can generate your own Spinner, having total control on the content shown and edition.

Comment: float is imprecisely, use Double